# How do I take a characters and turn it into a string? C++

Tags: c++

I'm just trying to use the alphabet to try and make words/names. When I do this the cout end up outputting nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char Alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string n;

    n[0] = Alphabet[10];
    n[1] = alphabet[4];
    n[2] = alphabet[21];
    n[3] = alphabet[8];
    n[4] = alphabet[13];
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: Because `n` isn't sized appropriately.

Comment: *"When I do this the cout end up outputting nothing."* - it's undefined behaviour; that it ends up printing nothing on your machine with your compiler settings and one particular test run is just a coincidence. It could also crash or do other, completely unrelated things.

Comment: make some space `n.resize(5)`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue here is that `n` is an empty string, meaning you're trying to access indexes that don't exist.

To add characters to the string, you could use the string member function, [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)

```
n.push_back(Alphabet[10]);
n.push_back(alphabet[4]);
...
```

Alternatively, [the `+=` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) would also work:

```
n += Alphabet[10];
n += alphabet[4];
...
```

Furthermore, I'd suggest using [`.at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) over the subscript operator (`[]`) with your strings, as `.at()` will do bounds checking for you (which would have made this issue a little more obvious).

Comment: No, using `at` is not recommended. It throws an exception, and that's almost always the wrong error handling strategy at such a low level. You cannot `catch` such an exception and "handle" it in any meaningful way. Just use `[]`. For debugging, a debug runtime can be used which detects out-of-bounds access and crashes immediately.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I disagree. I'd argue that there are two cases where your string index goes out of bounds: either you're expecting it (in which case you either do bounds checking yourself and never run the `.at`, so no exception is thrown, or you have a try/catch) or you're NOT expecting it, in which case having an exception and a program crash is a godsend for someone unaware of their bug. (furthermore, if this gets passed the developer and into the field, I'd prefer a program crash on the exception over continuing to run in a bad state with UB).

Comment: An out-of-bounds access in such a low-level container, which is hopefully wrapped by your own higher-level program components, must be a bug in your code. Exceptions are *not* for bugs but for designed behaviour in rare situations. Use `assert`s for your `operator[]` calls instead and make the application crash immediately if a precondition fails; this also avoids someone catching the exception and continuing execution.

Comment: P.S.: You will notice that `at` is an anomaly in the standard library. Other standard container classes or algorithms normally don't throw if preconditions are violated. For example, no exceptions are thrown if you use invalid iterators in some function.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a string with `string n;`, an empty string is created. It has length zero, therefore trying to access character positions within the string with `n[0]` etc. does not work. These simply do not exist at that point.

As said in another answer, you can use the member function `push_back` to add a character to a string, increasing its length by one.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `n` as `string n;`, then `n` will be an empty string (zero size and unspecified capacity), and accessing a string with an index beyond its size is undefined behaviour.

There are two principal ways to overcome this:

(1) Use operator `+=` like in `n += Alphabet[10];`, such that the string object will adapt its size accordingly. Note that this may lead to `realloc`-operations internally from time to time.

(2) if you know the size in advance, with `string n(5, ' ')` you may reserve enough space in advance (and fill the string up with blanks in this case), such that `realloc`-operations will not have to occur.